# Setting Core Data attribute to nil with NSBatchUpdateRequest

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Is it possible to set an attribute to `nil` using `NSBatchUpdateRequest`? Passing `NSNull()` to `propertiesToUpdate` isn't working:

```
let unlockRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "MyEntity")
unlockRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "self in %@", myObjectIDs)
unlockRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["lockDate": NSNull()]
var error: NSError?
myContext.executeRequest(unlockRequest, error: &error)
if let error = error {
    log.error("Failed to unlock: \(error)")
}
```

I don't get any errors, but it doesn't clear the date.

I've also tried setting it to `NSExpression(forConstantValue: NSNull())`, but that doesn't work either (`forConstantValue` argument does not accept an optional value, so I can't pass it `nil`.).

Comment: Did you try NSExpression(constantValue: nil) ?

Comment: @Willeke Sadly it doesn't accept an optional value, so I can't pass it nil.

Comment: @Sencha did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @Serluca No I never did, in the end I had to set my lock date to a date in the past to effectively invalidate the lock (acceptable for me but I'm sure not for other situations).

Answer (score 5):

Current API allows to pass `nil` as a constant value.

```
unlockRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["lockDate": NSExpression(forConstantValue: nil)]
```

Comment: I can see that the method signature now accepts Swift optionals. If this is verified to work then that would be the problem solved! `NSExpression.init(forConstantValue obj: Any?)`

Comment: The compiler doesn't complain, but when I execute the request it throws an exception: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid string key (null) passed to propertiesToUpdate:'`

Comment: The header for `NSBatchUpdateRequest.propertiesToUpdate` says: "The expressions can be any `NSExpression` that evaluates to a scalar value."

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work correctly in Objective-C:

```
NSBatchUpdateRequest *batch = [[NSBatchUpdateRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:entityName];
NSExpression *value = [NSExpression expressionForConstantValue: nil];
batch.propertiesToUpdate = @{@"lockDate": value};
batch.resultType = NSUpdatedObjectsCountResultType;
NSError *error;                
NSBatchUpdateResult *results = [self.privateContext executeRequest:batch error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but here is the way you do it in Swift, verified myself without any crash.

```swift
// Or Optional<Date>.none as Any
unlockRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["lockDate": Date?.none as Any]
```